# Dynamic vs dynamically created arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm in a Programming I class and this is an excerpt from my textbook:

"There are two basic ways to create an array, statically and dynamically. Note that a dynamically created array is not the same thing as a dynamic array; a dynamically created array can only be ﬁxed-size in C. "

My professor is saying things that pretty directly contradict this quote, and is being very evasive when I ask further questions. He doesn't seem to acknowledge that there is a difference between dynamic vs fixed-size and dynamically-created vs. statically-created. I don't know enough about C to argue with him and since he's the one who wrote the textbook, I'm a little lost at the moment.

1. What is the difference between statically-created vs. dynamically-created and dynamic vs. static arrays?
2. Do "dynamic" (not dynamically-created) arrays exist in C?

The textbook is "The Art and Craft of Programming: C Edition" by John Lusth. Actually I was wrong about my professor being the one who wrote it, the author is a different CS professor at my school.

Comment: Which text book are you quoting ?

Comment: Which textbook is it? I've never heard of a non-dynamic-but-dynamically-created array before. Is the book perhaps talking about [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Comment: /me mutters darkly about using C for 'Programming I'

Answer (score 3):

When the professor uses word dynamic it means that an array can change its size on the fly. That is new elements can be added to or deleted from the array.
A dynamically allocated array means the allocation of an array at run-time in the heap. Statically allocated arrays are allocated before the main function gets the control.

Take into account that C has Variable Length Arrays (VLA). Bit it is not the same as dynamic arrays. VLA means that an array may be recreated with different sizes. But in each such recreation you create a new array.

An example of a dynamic array is standard C++ class `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question will depend on how pedantially one wants to treat terms like "array" and "dynamic". Is "array" supposed to refer exclusibely to *array types*? Or are we allowed to include `malloc`-ed arrays as well, accessible through *pointers*? Does "dynamic" refer to dynamic memory (even though the standard C nomenclature does not use this term)? Or are we allowed to consider local *VLAs* as "dynamic" as well?

Anyway, one can separate arrays into three conceptual categories

1. Arrays with compile-time size
2. Arrays with run-time initial size, which cannot be resized
3. Arrays with run-time initial size, which can be resized

Apparently, your professor referred to the second category as "dynamically created arrays" and to the third category as "dynamic" arrays.

For example, arrays from the first category are the classic built-in C89/90-style C arrays

```
 int a[10];
```

Arrays from the second category are C99 VLAs

```
 int a[n];
```

(or `new`-ed arrays in C++).

Arrays from the third category are arrays allocated with `malloc`

```
 int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
```

which can be later resized with `realloc`.

Of course, once we step beyond the built-in features of the core language, the division between these categories becomes purely conceptual. It is just a matter of the interface the array implementation offers to the user. For example, it is possible to implement arrays from the third category through arrays of the second category, by destroying the old fixed-size array and allocating a new one of different size. In fact, that is how `realloc` is allowed to work in general case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the terminology is not formally defined, so when different people use these words, they may mean different things.

I think your textbook is distinguishing between these three definitions:

**Static array**

An array whose size is hard-coded into the source:

```
int ages[100];
ages[0] = 1;
```

- Disadvantage: you have to know how big to make it, when you code.
- Advantage: the runtime automatically takes back the storage when the variable goes out of scope.

**Dynamically allocated array**

An array whose size is decided at runtime, before creating the array.

```
numberOfAges = (some calculation);
int *ages = (int*) malloc(numberOfAges);
ages[0] = 1;
```

In this case, the size of the array isn't known at compile-time. It is decided at runtime, but once the array has been created, its size cannot change.

- Advantage: You can make it different sizes depending on runtime requirements.
- Disadvantage: You have to make your own code call `free()` to reclaim the storage.

**Dynamic arrays**

This is an array whose size grows or shrinks during its lifespan.

A hypothetical language might have statements like:

```
resize(ages, 5); // make "ages" 5 longer
truncate(ages, 3); // make "ages" 3 long, discarding later elements.
```

What your professor is saying, correctly, is that the core of C does not have arrays that can do this. A `char*` is a fixed size at the point it's allocated, and that can never change.

In C, if you want a list of values whose length grows or shrinks, you have to roll your own code to do it, or use a library of functions that provides it. Rather than working directly with arrays, you'd work with the API provided by the library. Indeed, it might look very much like the hypothetical example above, except that `ages` would not be an `int*` - it would be some type provided by the library.

```
#include <resizeableIntArrays.h>
...
ResizeableIntArray ages = allocateResizeableIntArray(100);
resize(ages,80);
```

There are lots of ways to achieve this - using `realloc()`, using linked lists or binary trees, using linked lists of arrays. I suspect when your professor is "evasive", he's really saving the more complicated stuff until later. Any respectable C course will get to this stuff eventually, but if ordinary arrays are new to you, it'll be a few weeks before you're ready for linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

statically created arrays are those whose size u give as a constant during the declaration, like

```
int arr[10];
```

dynamically created arrays are those whose size is given as a variable. as variables can take any value during the array declaration, size depends on the variable value at that program instance, like

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
```

for your second question: dynamic arrays (arrays that change their size during program execution) do not exist in C. u can create a link list with dynamic memory allocation, which would be in essence a dynamic linear data structure (in contrast to a static linear data structure that array is).

Answer (score 0):

*Dynamically created array* means array is created at run time. Either it would be a variable length arrays

```
int n = 5;
int a[n];
```

or created using `malloc`

```
int *a;
a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);  // But note that pointers are not arrays
```

In C, there is no *dynamic arrays*. You can't add or delete new elements to it, i.e. once an array is created its size can't be changed.